# How to open an OLEDBConnection through SSIS script task?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, oledb, oledbconnection

I need to process Excel files saved in a specific folder.

In my SSIS package I added a Foreach loop configured as a File Enumérator, populating a `filepath`variable. Then, a script task use this variable to open the Excel file and process it.

[image]

However, I'm not able to open the OLEDB Connection to my file in the script task.
The `filepath`contains the valid path. I added a test in my script to check the file.

Here is a sample of my code :

```
// Check file to process.
string rawfilePath = Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value.ToString().Replace(@"\",@"\\");

if (rawfilePath == String.Empty || !File.Exists(rawfilePath))
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, SCRIPT_TASK_NAME, "Invalid input file '" + rawfilePath + "'...", String.Empty, 0);

MessageBox.Show(rawfilePath);

// Open connection.
string rawFileConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='"
 + rawfilePath + "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1'";

MessageBox.Show(rawFileConnectionString);

OleDbConnection rawExcelConnection = new OleDbConnection(rawFileConnectionString);
rawExcelConnection.Open();
```

My folder is `C:\TestFolder`. It contains two files : `C:\TestFolder\export_20140101.xls` and `C:\TestFolder\export_20140102.xls`.

Here is the error :

[image]

In English

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Comment: Do your message boxes fire? Which line is failing, the instantiation of `rawExcelConnection` or the `Open` call?

Comment: Run it in debug mode or put your entire code into a try catch block, and use Dts.FireError with the exception message in the catch block

Comment: The try/catch block saved my life !.
The error was about the database engine (ACE 12.0). The driver was not found, I never installed it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, my script works.

The database engine ACE 12.0 was not installed on my local machine.
I downloaded the .exe package from Microsoft [website](http://www.microsoft.com/fr-FR/download/details.aspx?id=13255) then I changed the execution mode of my package from 64bit to 32 bit because the installed Microsoft Office version is a 32bit version (**Run64BitRuntime** to **FALSE** in project settings).

Here is a post about [how to run a 32 bit package in a 64 bit environnent](http://help.pragmaticworks.com/dtsxchange/scr/FAQ%20-%20How%20to%20run%20SSIS%20Packages%20using%2032bit%20drivers%20on%2064bit%20machine.htm).

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to replace the "\" with "\\" as you have with the check file to process.

The Compiler recognizes this when you are converting a DTS variable.

The compiler is recognizing your path as C:\\TestFolder\\export_20140102.xls

When that happens it sees two empty directories and can not return a value.

When the compiler reads a DTS variable it reads it as a literal string.

It should work if you change

```
string rawfilePath = Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value.ToString().Replace(@"\",@"\\");
```

to

```
string rawfilePath = Dts.Variables["User::FilePath"].Value.ToString());
```

Comment: In fact, both solutions work. The problem wasn't the URL formatting.